# Change slider from months to year

Tags: javascript

i have a code snippet that looks like this:

```
    `document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
        const month = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
        filterBy(month);
    });
}`
```

I want to change it so that the slider counts years instead of months.

I tried this:
`document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener('input', (e) => { const year = parseInt(e.target.value, 10); filterBy(year); }); }`

and changed the slider to "year" and also the range but it doesn't show the years from the geojson as it would with the months.

Comment: The only thing you changed compared to the original snippet, is renaming the variable from `month` to `year`, which results in the exact same behaviour. You will need to change the `filterBy()` function, please add the code of this function to the question.

Comment: Or maybe your `slider` element already does the "calculation" part, but in this case we'll need to see the implementation of this element, in order to see what could possibly be wrong.

Comment: I have a slider label that looks like this:
<label id="year"></label>
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="3" step="1" value="0">

And the filterby(year) looks like this:
    function filterBy(year) {
        const filters = ['==', 'year', year];
        map.setFilter('chargingstation-circles', filters);
        map.setFilter('chargingstation-labels', filters);

        document.getElementById('year').textContent = years[year];
    }

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.